# Instafeed pagination and limit not working for chosen tag, yet same code works for other tags

Tags: instagram-api, instafeedjs

The following [Instafeed](http://instafeedjs.com/) code shows not 5 but 6 images, and the `#load-more` button is hidden, indicating `hasNext()` is false:

```
var tagged_cofiwear = new Instafeed({
        target: 'instagram-tagged',
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'cofiwear',
        clientId: '8852afa8788546a199c37543b77b043c',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        limit: 5,
        template: '<a target="_blank" href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
        after: function() {
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                $('#load-more').hide();
            }
        }
    });
tagged_cofiwear.run();
$('#load-more').on('click', function() {
        tagged_cofiwear.next();
});
```

To try and troubleshoot, I found a jsfiddle with Instafeed pagination that works (http://jsfiddle.net/unuLyzx0/107/) and edited `tagName: 'justanotherinvegas'` to be `tagName: 'cofiwear'`.

Here is the result, which also shows the wrong number and the load more button doesn't work  :(

http://jsfiddle.net/unuLyzx0/108/

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else:

Turns out I needed to add the `userId` and `accessToken` for the user cofiwear, which happens to be the tag we want from all users.